# How to make method thread safe, even I forget to add synchronization on method or block level without changing file?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

While one of the reputed company Interview I got question like:

You have one class and your colleague has forget to synchronize some important methods
How do you make it thread safe without changing in same class?

```
public class Account{

    //some variables

    public boolean withdraw()
    {
        //some business logic
        return true;
    }

    public boolean deposite()
    {
        //some business logic
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what could be the answer, It could be silly answer as well. please help me to get answer for this.

My answer:
I given answer like we can make wrapper over it and We can synchronize. It was not convincing answer, I thought this is best platform to get answer

Comment: Do you mean "How to make `Account` thread-safe without changing `Account`"?

Comment: And why *wrapping* is not convincing?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  It was not convincing and got counter question is anyone can call that class method directly Right !!! uhhhh.. :)

Answer (score 4):

I see two possible answers here:

1. Extend the Acount class and synchronize the method access:

```
public class SyncrhonizedAccess extends Account {
   public synchronized boolean withdraw() {
     return super.withdraw();
   }

   public synchronized boolean deposite() {
      return super.deposite();
   }
}
```

2. Wrap the class and synchronize the access on the wrapped object:

```
public class AccountWrapper {
    private final Account realAcount;

    public AccountWrapper(Account realAccount) {
       this.realAccount = realAccount;
    }

    public synchronized boolean withdraw()
    {
       return realAccount.withdraw();
    }

    public synchronized boolean deposite()
    {
        return realAccount.deposite();
    }
}
```

Now both methods can be done in variety of ways (manually like I've shown), auto-generated (that boils down to one of the aforementioned method just done "automatically" by libraries like CGLIB (Byte Code Generation Library)), or even using AOP (Aspect-oriented programming).

Another side note is that instead of using word `synchronized` one could create a lock and synchronize on it internally inside the method.

Of course this all makes sense if `Account` class has a shared state - data fields that are actually changed and accessed by both `withdraw` and `deposite` methods. Otherwise you don't really have to synchronize anything.

Comment: `deposite()` returns `super.synchronize()`? I assume a typo but I want to double check I'm not missing anything.

Comment: @cameron1024: Of course, you're right. Its a typo, sorry. I meant super.deposite() of course. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Looks like this is the best that could be done. But initial `Account` class still has not thread-safe public methods. Maybe interviewers failed to formulate the question correctly, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use one aspect and synchronize the calls to the methodos. I would choose this option given that since the other points of my application or third-party libraries the methods are being invoked

**Code Example:**

```java
@Aspect
public class AspectAccount {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    @Pointcut("execution(* path.to.package.Account.*(..) )")
    public void callAt() {
    }

    @Around("callAt()")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```